# FB Graph API - get places visited by my friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to fetch all places visited by my friends using Facebook Graph API (or FQL). But I'm unsuccessfull.

Is any chance to get the same results like Graph search on Facebook web? I want to fetch exactly the same like this:
https://www.facebook.com/search/me/friends/places-visited

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could basically use a FQL like the following:

```
select author_uid, target_id from checkin where author_uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())
```

but you need to gather the page information separately.